# After a repair/chkdsk, all NTFS junction points are gone

Tags: windows-7, ntfs, user-profiles, filesystem-corruption

I've been repairing a Windows 7 64-bit installation. In the process, the Windows partition was subjected to several rounds of automatic repair, `chkdsk`, `sfc`, even a volume shrink. Long story. Anyway, after I'm done, Windows mostly works, but it seems that all NTFS junction points - like `c:\Users\Username\Start menu` - are not junctions anymore, they're just empty folders.

I can't really tell on which stage did this happen. Stages were many, and Windows won't boot in the meantime. The filesystem on the partition was NTFS all along though.

Is this a known condition, is there a wholesale solution to this? Barring that, is there a user profile fixing routine which restores the proper folder/junction/permission structure?

Comment: If that is true, then you WinSxS directory is probably screwed up. Some program may fail to run.

Comment: I've scanned Windows\WinSxS on another Win7 box - didn't find any junctions. So probably not.

Comment: Cave and pave, or use a restore point.

Comment: @vcsjones: I though WinSxS uses hardlinks, not reparse points?

Comment: Hardlinks should not be affected. To kill a junction, it's enough to flip an attribute; hardlinks are just regular file records.